# Can't hide NSStatusItem from status bar?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to add an option to my app settings to hide the icon from the status bar. It currently looks like this inside my AppDelegate :

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    statusItem?.button?.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "paperplane.fill", accessibilityDescription: nil)

    if let menu = menu {
        statusItem?.menu = menu
    }
}
```

I'm trying to hide it from a preference pane view controller with the following code :

```
@IBAction func hideicon(_ sender: Any) {
    if hideicon.state.rawValue == 1 {
        NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength).isVisible = false
    } else {
        NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength).isVisible = true
    }
}
```

But the button is still showing. Trying to edit the button image isn't working either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `statusItem?.isVisible = false` should work. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Edited, hope it's more clear. statusItem?.isVisible = false doesn't work.

Comment: You're creating a new status item in `hideicon`.

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
@IBAction func hideicon(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if hideicon.state.rawValue == 1 {
  
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.statusItem?.isVisible = false
        
        
        
    } else {
        
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.statusItem?.isVisible = true
        
    }
}
```

Simply solved my issue.

Comment: This all simplifies to just `appDelegate.statusItem?.isVisible = hideicon.state.rawValue != 1`.